# How to check and restrict data usage for each application on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, internet

In Ubuntu 20.04 whenever I connect to internet through usb tethering , data is being used in background about 2 Mbps.
And this affects current application's downloading speed .
How to identify which app is using data and **restrict** data usage for that particular app?